# Creating Index on a View with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, view

So I'm trying to create an index on the example view I have here. At first I had the COUNT_BIG error so I added that in but now I'm this getting error

> Cannot create the clustered index ... because the select list of the view contains an expression on result
>   of aggregate function or grouping column.

```
SELECT        
SALE_DATE, 
DATEPART(YEAR, SALE_DATE) AS SALE_YEAR, 
CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, SALE_DATE), 0) AS DATE) AS SALE_MONTH, 
CAST(DATEADD(QUARTER, DATEDIFF(QUARTER, 0, SALE_DATE), 0) AS DATE) AS SALE_QUARTER, 
REGION, 
A_ID, 
B_ID, 
ISNULL(SUM(SALE_VALUE), 0) AS SALE_VALUE, 
ISNULL(SUM(ADV_COMM), 0) AS ADV_COMM, 
ISNULL(SUM(CASH_COMM), 0) AS CASH_COMM, 
...
and a load more SUM columns in the exact same format
...
COUNT_BIG(*) AS COUNT 
FROM dbo.sale_data 
GROUP BY SALE_DATE, REGION, A_ID, B_ID

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_View_daily_sale_data 
ON view_daily_sale_data_test(SALE_DATE, A_ID, B_ID, REGION);
```

I have tried everything to work out what is actually wrong with this, removing group by, changing the columns that I'm indexing, removing the CAST's, I've read a lot of places you can include SUM by as long as you include COUNT_BIG.

Can someone just explain what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks!

Comment: According to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28v=sql.100%29.aspx, indexed views are supported for views with "Scalar aggregates, including SUM and COUNT_BIG without GROUP BY."

Answer (score 2):

The error message isn't too hard to decode:

> contains an expression

```
ISNULL(...)
```

> on result of aggregate function

```
SUM(...)
```

So, you're not allowed to do anything further to the *result* of an aggregate function.

Here, what I'd suggest is to create one view that just performs the `SUM()` operations, and is indexed, and then, if necessary, another view that just queries this first view, isn't indexed, and contains the `ISNULL()` expressions. Querying this second view (if appropriate hints are used or you're on a good SKU) should still massively benefit from the indexes on the first view.